# Is there any difference between String.split(" ") and String.split(/ +/g)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`"some string".split(" ")` => ["some", "string"]

`"some string".split(/ +/g)` => ["some", "string"]

It returns the same thing. Any difference?

Comment: Try it with two or more spaces between words and see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you had `"some    string"` with multiple spaces, the first one will get you:

```
Array(5) [ "some", "", "", "", "string" ]
```

The second one will treat multiple spaces as one:

```
Array [ "some", "string" ]
```